# Is it possible to decrypt SSL/TLS traffic with wireshark?

Tags: networking, encryption, ssl, wireshark

I'm trying to analyze the outgoing requests of an application on my windows 10 computer, but I'm not aware of any way to capture the secret key needed to decrypt the traffic. I have used [Teleriks Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) previously, but switched because of lack of protocol support.

I know the key can be captured on chrome/firefox by setting the "SSLKEYLOGFILE" enviroment variable, but this is not relevant in this case, as the application in question does not support that type of logging.

Therefore my question becomes:
*Is there a general method of capturing the secret key needed to decrypt SSL/TSL traffic in Wireshark, that can be applied regardless of application?*

## Answer

**There is no general way of capturing the secret key needed to decrypt SSL/TSL messages, but one can use a proxy such as [PolarProxy](https://www.netresec.com/?page=PolarProxy) to achieve equivalent results in most cases, hence I found the "general method" I was looking for.**

Comment: I'm assuming every application (or library) will have its own way of setting up the keys, so there will be no general way of capturing it. You will need to better understand how your application works, and what HTTP/TLS client library it uses.

Comment: Wouldn't that render TLS useless if you could simply capture the secret key with Wireshark?  Something tells me the _bad guys_ would have figured that one out a long time ago! :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answers, this was exactly what I was looking for!